# Estimate of Inverse Hessian Using SciPy Minimization

Tags: python, numpy, optimization, scipy

I am using SciPy's 'minimize' function to minimize a function. The function returns the optimal value, along with an estimated Jacobian and Hessian. As below:

```
fun: -675.09792378630596
hess_inv: <8x8 LbfgsInvHessProduct with dtype=float64>
jac: array([  6.34713615e-02,   1.15960574e-03,   1.63709046e-03, 2.16914486e-02,  -8.02970135e-02,  -4.39513315e-02,
6.69160727e-02,  -5.68434189e-05])
message: b'CONVERGENCE: REL_REDUCTION_OF_F_<=_FACTR*EPSMCH'
nfev: 684
nit: 60
status: 0
success: True
x: array([  9.93756778e-01,   3.51823214e+00,  -2.06368373e-01, 7.37395700e-04,   2.11222756e-02,   3.29367564e-02, 1.22886906e-01,  -2.75434386e-01])
```

I want the estimated Hessian, but when I have it return hess_inv, all I get returned is

```
<8x8 LbfgsInvHessProduct with dtype=float64>
```

rather than the maxtrix itself. How do I have it return the matrix?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [SciPy documentation for the LbfgsInvHessProduct](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.16.0/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.LbfgsInvHessProduct.html); you can use the method **todense()** to obtain the LbfgsInvHessProduct's values as a dense array.

However, keep in mind the LbfgsInvHessProduct is still a matrix! It's a special memory-optimized format, but you can still call other matrix functions such as matmat(), transpose(), dot() etc.