# Minimize function won't show me the hessian

Tags: minimize, hessian-matrix

I minimized a function and need it's (inverse) Hessian for the standard errors.

the function gives me this for the (inverse) Hessian:

```
hess_inv: <5x5 LbfgsInvHessProduct with dtype=float64>
```

I expected a matrix here?  I tried `list(hess_inv)` but that does not work.

P.S. Am I correct that the square root of the diagonalvalues equals the standard errors?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Estimate of Inverse Hessian Using SciPy Minimization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42288740/estimate-of-inverse-hessian-using-scipy-minimization)

Comment: I see now that paisanco is right and this is a duplicate of another topic. However, I don't understand the solution there: I do not understand how to use the todense() function correctly. I tried to use toarray() instead but also got an error. I cannot comment on the other topic yet because I am a new user. If  someone here can explain it, that will be appreciated very much

Answer (score 0):

`parameters.hess_inv` will give you the inverse hessian matrix